# Preventing multiple async startActivity calls in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a listView with items that, when clicked, create an intent and start an activity with that intent using the `startActivity` method.

The issue is that items can be pressed multiple times while the asynchronous call to `startActivity` is made, which will open multiple activities one on top of each other.

Using the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` doesn't solve it either, perhaps because the activity being opened from intent 1 hasn't been placed at the top of the stack when intent 2 fires?

How can I handle this?

Manifest:

```
<activity
  android:name=".Activity2"
  android:parentActivityName=".Activity1"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Intent code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("a", "b");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your Manifest file inside activity tag add android:launchMode="singleTask"

```
  <activity
            android:name="YourActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Comment: This is the same as setting an intent flag and doesn't work either for me

Comment: not the same your flag like other value  android:launchMode="singleTop" not singleTask

Comment: I missed that sorry, but that still does not work. I have updated the question with the relevant code. When trying singleTask, I removed the intent flag.

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` intent flag instead of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`